# Exjts 4.2 get sort direction in headerclick

Tags: sorting, grid, extjs4, listener, multiple-columns

i am now want to get the grid column sorting direction for me to customized the sort function. May i know how i can have the sort direction in the below headerclick function.

```
headerclick: function(header, column, e, t,eOpts)
```

Answer (score 0):

The grid column sorting indicator is only UI to sorters that are implemented at store level. You can access the sorters by [`grid.getStore().getSorters()`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/ext/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getSorters).